# How do you create a Hello World test using Python Behave in the Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I do not understand how to create a hello world test using python behave in the Linux terminal.

I have just started learning BDD and Python Behave specifically. I've created a Feature directory and a steps folder. Within that folder, I have a .py file whose contents I copied from the Behave documentation site for the purpose of practicing.

I've also created a helloWorld.py file with simple code that prints 'Hello World'. But how exactly do I create a Python Behave Hello World test? I am using the Linux terminal and do not have access to an IDE for this.

Just for reference if needed: https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I have never used stack overflow so forgive me for any violations.

A .py file whose contents I copied from the Behave documentation site for the purpose on practicing. Here's the code just in case:

```
from behave import *

@given('we have behave installed')
def step_impl(context):
   pass

@when('we implement a test')
def step_impl(context):
   assert True is not False

@then('behave will test it for us!')
def step_impl(context):
   assert context.failed is False
```

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

- Download/Clone the [behave repository](https://github.com/behave/behave) and run `bin/behave more.features/tutorial.feature` which is referenced in the README and by you above (hint: install behave if you are lacking Python dependencies for behave)

  - [more.features/tutorial.feature](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/more.features/tutorial.feature)
  - [more.features/steps/tutorial_steps.py](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/more.features/steps/tutorial_steps.py)
- Use [behave.example docs: Tutorial 1](http://behave.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial01.html) ([behave.exaple repository](https://github.com/behave/behave.example)) that already contains executable examples